# How can I write each line output in a file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

This is part of my script:

```
num=`wc -l /tmp/list.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`
for i in $(seq $num)
do
    touch /tmp/pages/$i.txt
done

#OR:

#awk '{system("touch /tmp/pages/"NR".txt")}' /tmp/list.txt
i=1
for line in $(cat list.txt)
do
    #for (( i = 1; i <= num; i++ )) 
    #do
    wget $line --no-check-certificate -O /tmp/pages/$i.txt
    i= i+1
    #done
done
```

How can I assign the output of each line in `list.txt` to my `i` variable?

For example:

```
line one > 1.txt

line two > 2.txt
```

And so on...

Comment: You want to do this instead of putting the `wget` result in the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i=1
while read line
do
    echo "$line" > /tmp/pages/$i.txt
    let i=i+1
done < list.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print > NR".txt"}' list.txt
```